# How to split an Array into Odd Array and Even Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with splitting the array into to separate arrays Odd and Even.
What I did was:

```
componentDidMount() {
 axios.get( `${this.props.cmsUrl}types/genres`)
 .then(response => { if ( response.data !== undefined ) {

  let even = [];
  let odd = [];
  let allData = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", ];

  for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; ++i) {
    if ( ( allData[i] % 2 ) === 0) { 
      even.push(allData[i]);
    } 
    else { 
      odd.push(allData[i]); 
    }
  };
  console.log("allData : ",allData);
  console.log("even : ",even);
  console.log("even : ",odd);
 }}
)
}
```

What I really was expecting is

```
allData = [a, b, c, d]
odd = [a , c]
even = [b, d]
```

But what really happened is

```
allData = even 
odd = empty array
```

is this my problem  => `( allData[i] % 2 ) === 1`

The console.log is :

```
  allData :  (8) ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]0: "a"1: "b"2: "c"3: 
  "d"4: "e"5: "f"6: "g"7: "h"length: 8__proto__: Array(0)
    details.js:56 even :  []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
    details.js:57 odd :  (8) ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]0: 
   "a"1: "b"2: "c"3: "d"4: "e"5: "f"6: "g"7: "h"length: 8__proto__: Array(0)
```

Thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce. https://jsfiddle.net/drs8opk7/

Comment: can u log response.data and put results in your question ?

Comment: Mr Soroush_Neshat : This is the console log 

     allData :  (8) ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]0: "a"1: "b"2: "c"3: "d"4: "e"5: "f"6: "g"7: "h"length: 8__proto__: Array(0)
        details.js:56 even :  []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
        details.js:57 odd :  (8) ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]0: "a"1: "b"2: "c"3: "d"4: "e"5: "f"6: "g"7: "h"length: 8__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: @Ranny tnx for infos . i posted the answer to solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to use **charCodeAt** method because **allData** is an array of string not array of numbers.

It's the solution of your problem:

```
if ( ( allData[i].charCodeAt(0) % 2 ) === 0) { your code }
```

=================

as **Thomas Scheffer** mentioned it seems u want to sort based on character index  not its value .

so if u want to sort based on index u have to write :

```
if ( ( i % 2 ) === 0) { your code }
```

it converts like this :

```
allData = ["b","f","z","w"] => { odd=["f","w"], even=["b","z"]  }
```

but if u want to sort based on character value u have to write :

```
if ( ( allData[i].charCodeAt(0) % 2 ) === 0) { your code }
```

it converts like this :

```
allData = ["b","f","z","w"] => { odd=["w"] , even=["b","f","z"] }
```

Comment: Or just use `if( ( i % 2 ) === 0 ){ }` as its about the index number not really the data  in allData.

Comment: @Soroush_Neshat Thaaaaaaaaaank you very much it is working now

Comment: @ThomasScheffer if characters are shuffled u cant do that anymore

Comment: @Soroush_Neshat `charCodeAt()` returns the ASCII code for the first character in that value. Not sure if thats what @Ranny was asking for.

Comment: @ThomasScheffer well i am not sure lets ask him .

Comment: @Ranny do u want to sort character based on its index in the array or the value of character?

Comment: @ThomasScheffer @ Soroush_Neshat Thanks for your interesting, yes i want the index to be my lead, and actually all @Soroush_Neshat solutions was good for me even `charCodeAt()` has solved my question.

Comment: @Ranny Just remember that Arrays start at 0, so this will skew your expected results. As `"a"` would be in even instead of odd.

Comment: Thank you for the clarify @ThomasScheffer, i am okay with the results of@Soroush_Neshat answer, Thank you both

Answer (score 1):

instead of for loops you can use filter method

```js
/*ES6*/

let evenArray = result.filter((a,i) => i%2);
let oddArray = result.filter((a,i) => !(i%2));

/*ES5*/

let evenArray = result.filter(function(a,i){return i%2});
let oddArray = result.filter(function(a,i){return !(i%2)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right condition is `if ( ( allData[i] % 2 ) === 0)`

Try in console:

```
4 % 2
4 % 3
```

Comment: That flip my empty array to be same allData and second one is empty

Comment: Can you print your `allData` array?

Comment: if i made : 
if ( ( allData[i] % 2 ) === 0)  and  else if ( ( allData[i] % 2 ) === 1)
both arrays are empty now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
let allData = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" ];

const { even, odd } = allData.reduce((acc, val, index) => {
    const key = index % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even';
    return {
       ...acc,
       [key]: acc[key].concat(val),
    };
}, { odd: [], even: [] });

console.log( 'even', even );
console.log( 'odd', odd );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let allData = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", ];

let even = [];
let odd = [];

for (let i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
if (i % 2 == 0) {
    even.push(allData[i]);
} else {
    odd.push(allData[i]);
}
}

console.log("Even array is : " + even);
console.log("Even array is : " + odd);
```